# Search for text in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I need to make search in some textbox(or some other control) but I cannot find good solution ...

To be more clear I have one text box and when i type text in it,i need to highlight text in other `control`.

In winform app I write code for this, and I use `RichTextBox`, that was not a big problem.

But in windows store application I not have `RichTextBox`, here are `RichTextBlock` and `RichEditBox` and with this controls i cannot find way to search for text.

Is this even possible? maybe I can use some external library?
Please help and Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TextBox (for inputs) and TextBlock (for highlight content).
The TextBox control has an event named TextChanged raised every key pressed. TextBlock has a property named Inlines inside you can put some text element (like Span, Run, etc).
Your TextBlock can be declared like this :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTb">
    Lorem ipsum sit amet
</TextBlock>
```

Your TextBox :

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

And the TextChanged event :

```
var txtToHighlight = (sender as TextBox)?.Text;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtToHighlight))
{
    var tb = MyTb;
    var currentTxt = tb.Text;
    tb.Inlines.Clear();
    var ix = currentTxt.IndexOf(txtToHighlight);
    if (ix >= 0)
    {
        var highlightContent = new Span { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) };
        highlightContent.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = currentTxt.Substring(ix, txtToHighlight.Length) });

        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = currentTxt.Substring(0, ix) });
        tb.Inlines.Add(highlightContent);
        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = currentTxt.Substring(ix + txtToHighlight.Length) });
    }
    else
    {
        tb.Text = currentTxt;
    }
}
```